# Windows 8.1 update not showing

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, windows-8.1, windows-store

I have Windows 8 Pro activated with kms.
when I open windows store, it doesn't show "win8.1 available".
clicking on ms-windows-store:WindowsUpgrade just brings me to windows store main screen

slmgr /dli shows volume_kmsclient channel

I can upgrade it to WMC. Laptop is W8Pro WMC and update is available,
it's retail channel

Is W8 for KMS clients delayed or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 8.1 Update is only shown to Retail licenses and **not Volume Licenses** (volume_kmsclient) of Windows 8.

**Why can't I find the update in the Store?**

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/why-can-t-find-update-store

> Some editions of Windows 8 don’t support the free update to Windows
>   8.1. These include:
>
> - Windows 8 Enterprise
> - Editions of Windows 8 Pro that are installed by enterprises using KMS activation
> - Editions of Windows 8 that are installed using an MSDN ISO, and activated using multiple activation keys

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable. The important followup question is: how do I then update a Volume Licensed Windows 8?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn You need to download the ISO of the VL Edition from the VL portal, mount the ISO and run the setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

Although the Windows 8.1 update is downloaded and installed from the Store,in some cases your PC needs another update, KB 2871389, before Windows 8.1 becomes available to you in the Store.

If you’re using Windows Update to get automatic updates, KB 2871389 will be downloaded and installed automatically.

If you’ve turned off automatic updates, or if your PC is so new that automatic updates haven't been downloaded yet, or if you’d rather not wait for Windows Update to do this automatically, you can go to Windows Update and install KB 2871389 manually.

Or you can download the package from the link below and install:

[X64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/B/67BB1487-B67A-4B3C-BF49-140AB1CF7B5F/Windows8-RT-KB2871389-x64.msu)

[X86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/C/6/0C67F34D-1F09-429D-B55E-794177982162/Windows8-RT-KB2871389-x86.msu)

If you still don't see the update on the Store home screen after installing the KB 2871389 update, copy and open this link on your browser: ms-windows-store:WindowsUpgrade

Comment: I have autoupdate on, that update was already installed.
VL activations can't update to 8.1 through winstore, that's the problem

Comment: then try restarting pc.
in some cases changing location to US from pc settings also worked

Comment: (-1) Ankit, I already posted the correct answer. KMS activation based system don't get the update. That is the issue, not the update.