# What is the easiest way to upgrade to Windows 8.1 if you cannot do it via the Windows Store?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade, volume-license

I have a MSDN Subscription and have installed Windows 8 Professional using my Volume License version of Windows 8.

The Windows 8.1 update does not show up in Windows Store. This is a [known problem](https://superuser.com/questions/661317/windows-8-1-update-not-showing).

What is the appropriate, easiest way to upgrade this installation to Windows 8.1?

Comment: You get it from MSDN by clicking on Subscriber Downloads, of course.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sure, the ISO images are there. Am I supposed to boot from one of those? I don't want to reinstall from scratch, I want an upgrade.

Comment: Mount it and run the setup.exe, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volume License versions of Windows 8 are not able to be updated by using the Store. You must download the VL version of Windows 8.1, and can fully automate the process by running “setup.exe /auto:upgrade” from the Windows 8.1 installation files. This will perform an “In-place update”. This is explained further in the [Springboard Series Blog’s](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2013/10/18/windows-8-1-general-availability-the-it-pro-perspective.aspx) latest post.

Hope this helps,