# After Windows 10 upgrade - signing out or switching user freezes

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I upgraded from Windows 8 (not 8.1) to Windows 10. I have a high percentage CPU usage on System interrupts, about 5%.

I'm able to shut down restart and sleep, but when I sign out I get a black screen and keyboard stops working (num-lock caps-lock). If I try to switch users instead (win+l to lock and then select different user) It just spins forever on login.

One user is admin other is standard. It doesn't matter which user I log in as, neither can successfully sign out or switch to the other user.

Please help! Thanks

Comment: You performed a clean install from Windows 8.  So I wouldn't be shocked if your installation was not actually activated.  I suggest you revert back to Windows 8, perform the upgrade to Windows 8.1, then upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: It's not a clean install, upgrade install from 8 to 10(kept programs and files). [It's a volume license of Windows 8 not eligible for windows 8.1.](http://superuser.com/questions/662736/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-upgrade-to-windows-8-1-if-you-cannot-do-it-via-the-wi),  It says it's activated on Windows 10.

Comment: I can only share what I know.  The system requirements for a Windows 10 upgrade is suppose to be either Windows 7 SP1 or Windows 8.1 Update.  I don't feel like trying to find the chart currently.  Have you ran SFC and DISM by chance?

Comment: sfc and dism found no errors. I also created a new user account to see if something in the existing accounts was corrupt. Same result though, even a brand new account still freezes on sign out.

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 are you using? You can use command 'ver' to check your version. Is this question still valid?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get back to a log in screen by doing a cold boot.  That got old fast so I tried a warm boot to switch users and that seems to work well.

Not the solution I wanted but at least we can switch users several times a day with a warm boot.  Each user must save their files before switching users.

Comment: What video card do you have? Also, that is definitely not a solution :D

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues with a desktop at home and workstation in the office.  I have found if I RDP into the workstation I am able to login without and problems.  When I disconnect the RDP session the login screen returns on the host computer.  This is certainly not a solution, but it saves on the hard reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a Fresh install of Windows 10 Latest (1803 - April Update)
[Download From Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)